# QuickOSM Nominatim API failed，Connection timed out when running a query

Tags: quickosm

I was trying to download the green space of Fuzhou city, it failed, then I narrow the range to just a  district below Fuzhou City, it also failed. QuickOSM always reminds me of 'Nomination API failed', but I don't know why.

QuickOSM time out :900, Qgis time out:10000
Overpass API: https://overpass-api.de/api/
Nomination API: https://nominatim.qgis.org/search?

QuickOSM.core.exceptions.NetWorkErrorException: Nominatim API : download failed：Connection timed out
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/Flyfei/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\api\nominatim.py", line 48, in error
raise NetWorkErrorException('Nominatim API', ', '.join(messages))
QuickOSM.core.exceptions.NetWorkErrorException: Nominatim API : download failed：Connection timed out

Python： 3.9.18 (heads/master:c290dc6, Jan 14 2024, 01:36:02) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
QGIS： 3.28.15-Firenze Firenze, 252ad49ddc